# How to view public packages in Verdaccio

Tags: npm, verdaccio

Is there a way to view the public package downloaded from the npm repository at http://127.0.0.1:4873 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to show cached packages (public from npmjs by default) on the user interface still not possible, you can read more on this [issue](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/discussions/706).